# Samsung Series 5 BIOS not detecting any bootable devices

Tags: laptop, boot, bios, desktop

so I have a problem with my BIOS, it doesn't detect any bootable devices from the `Boot` tab.

```
NOTE: I'm gonna refer to keys and tabs that show in my BIOS settings page for ease of explanation. Please refer to the images below to see such tabs/keys.
```

So here is what happened:

I have a Windows installation in my HDD. I was trying to install Ubuntu from a USB drive, it showed up when I pressed F10 (key in this computer to select the device to boot from) but it wouldn't boot from the USB just like that, so I entered into the BIOS settings and in the `Advanced` tab I read on the right that by disabling `Fast boot mode` legacy USB is supported, so I disabled it, saved and reset. But it wouldn't boot anyway, I played around with some settings but nothing had changed to this point... even though I couldn't boot from USB, my Windows was still booting from my HDD.

But in one of those times I was changing settings, I mispressed F9 (loads optimised defaults) instead of F10 and hit enter, and from here I can't see ANY bootable devices under the `Boot` tab and now I can't even boot Windows anymore, as well not from my USB either. When I power on my laptop, it just shows the *Samsung* splash and it enters in the settings page by itself.

Can anyone please help me get my bootable devices found by the BIOS again? Thanks in advance!!

Here is my current BIOS settings:

[image: SysInfo tab][image: Advanced tab][image: Boot tab][image: no boot devices][image: no bootable devices on F10]

Comment: Try restoring the defaults in the bios and allow it to continue once so it can re-detect the hardware.  Recommend http://rufus.akeo.ie/ for creating a bootable USB from an ISO, found many other popular utilities did not work.

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work. I tried that a few times, but it just continues to a blank screen. I'll continue checking. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: If all else fails, checkout https://bsod.at/blog/2012/12/09/windows-8-broke-my-pc-samsung-series-9-bios-reset/ which says take out the battery and wait.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OK I figured it out.

Under the `Boot` tab I needed to Disable `Secure boot`, this added an option to choose a boot option which includes `CSM`, `UEFI` and `CSM and UEFI`.
Searching over the web I found that, at least the BIOS version in Samsung Series 5 (not sure if all Series X) does not work quite well with UEFI by itself, but it needs compatibility support.

So by using `CSM` or `CSM and UEFI` I was able to get my bootable devices listed again (I still wonder why the maker sets UEFI as an "optimised" default if it's not totally supported).

And by disabling `Fast boot mode` under `Advanced` tab, bootable USB is now running!

Anyways, thanks for your help!! :)

Comment: thanks for sharing. for my case i only need to disable fast boot

Answer (score 7):

I am posting this answer since this same problem for the model NP300E5X Series is not available anywhere.

The solution to this problem is:

1. Go to BIOS settings.
2. In ADVANCED tab, disable fast boot.
3. In BOOT tab, enable UEFI Boot.

That's it. :)

Comment: This worked for my Samsung Series 5 model NP535U3C laptop. Thanks.

Comment: this worked for me as well.